# PHP - How can I hide the first item in a Foreach temporarily?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code. How can I temporarily hide the first item on echo/name?

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <?php foreach($arrCategoria as $cat) { ?>
  <li role="" class="<?php echo $cat->slug==$catAtual ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/produtos/?c='.$cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by "temporarily". At what point do you want it to re-appear.

Comment: `<?php foreach(array_slice($arrCategoria, 1) as $cat) { ?>` will prevent it from being rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By PHP

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php $i = 0;
    foreach ($arrCategoria as $cat) { ?>
        <li <?php if ($i == 0) {
            echo "style='display:none;'";
        }
        ?> role="" class="<?php echo $cat->slug == $catAtual ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/produtos/?c=' . $cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php $i++;
} ?>
</ul>
```

Or by CSS

```
li:first-child { display: none; }
```

Comment: Tanks! This solved my problem to:
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
 <?php foreach($arrCategoria as $cat) { if($cat->slug=='categoria-excluir') { continue; } ?>
 <li role="" class="<?php echo $cat->slug==$catAtual ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/produtos/?c='.$cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>